# Where did Decim send Chiyuki? To reincarnation or to void?

Tags: death-parade

I saw that the mask changed and she just gave in to her wish to come back to live in her last 'test', so I think she was sent to void, but I'm not really sure. Can somebody explain, please?

Comment: OMG I watched this quite a while ago with a friend and we had that debate. I believe he sent her to reincarnation but the fact of how she responded to his test broke everything he believed in. So he wept tears of hope, tears of joy and tears of saddeness. It was quite moving. But this is my opinion I don't think there was a concrete answer.

Answer (score 5):

She went to

> Reincarnation 
>  [image: White mask] This scene happens immediately after her elevator door closes.

Answer (score 1):

She was sent to reincarnation represented by the sign above the elevator. One sitting on the chair is a mannequin it has no eye balls.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in episode 11, in Ginti's bar, when he sent Harada and that girl, it was shown to be the reincarnation mask, but soon enough it changed to the void mask. We can always see the reincarnation lift is on the left and the void lift is on the right.

Decim sent Chiyuki to the elevator on the right which is usually the void one. However, there was a reincarnation mask. Here comes what happened in Ginti's place: he switched the masks. Probably Decim would also have done the same.

Well, the mannequin, regardless of whether he sent her to void or reincarnation, he merely made it for remembrance.

Answer (score 0):

In episode 12, it shows Chiyuki in the chair, but it isn't her because she would've dissolved into dust. It's her mannequin, meaning she was sent into the void.

[image: screenshot of episode 12]

Comment: IIRC don't people who go to reincarnate also get mannequins? The whole point of the mannequin was to be a mememento of the life that was right?

Answer (score 0):

She was sent for reincarnation. However, because Decim had an experience with her, he made a dummy to represent her because she was sent to reincarnation and her reincarnated body would look different.

Answer (score -2):

She was sent to reincarnation. Why I think so? Because we could get to see the reincarnation sign over the elevator, right  after it closed.

About the mannequin that was shown later, it was, I think a fake one that Decim made. I am a little bit confused about that, but if we think that she was sent to void, then that sign over the elevator would be shown to be kinda meaningless.